# How to make order by field work only when it meets specific condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to order mysql query results by field topped_time only when it's earlier than now.For example, if topped_time is 2016-7-6, it should be taken into consideration, but if topped_time is 2016-7-16, it should be ignored.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY IF(`topped_time` < CURRENT_TIME(), '`topped_time` DESC', ''), `published_time` DESC
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY CASE WHEN `topped_time=` < CURRENT_TIME() THEN `topped_time` END, `published_time` DESC
```

still ordering by topped_time even when it's later than now.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `published_time` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `topped_time` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `article` (`id`, `published_time`, `topped_time`) VALUES
(1, '2016-07-05 22:01:14', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, '2016-07-05 22:01:23', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(3, '2016-07-05 22:01:25', '2016-07-07 00:00:00'),
(4, '2016-07-05 22:01:27', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(5, '2016-07-05 22:01:29', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

[image]

The correct order from this screenshot should be id:4,5,3,2,1, because the topped_time of id 4 is 2016-07-06 00:00:00, which is earlier than now, and should be the first one. While the topped_time of id 3 is 2016-07-07 00:00:00, and is later than now, which should be ignored.

what's the correct query or is it impossible?

Comment: What's the expected output? Some example rows/example output would be greatly helpful.

Comment: i just updated the question

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: I may got the answer myself:  SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY `topped_time` < CURRENT_TIME() and topped_time DESC, `published_time` DESC

Comment: @Alvin your solution will not work if you will have multiple `topped_time < CURRENT_TIME()` rows as it returns 0 or 1, try my solution instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is your choice:

```
SELECT * FROM `article`
ORDER BY 
    IF (`topped_time` < NOW(), `topped_time`, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') DESC, 
    `published_time`  DESC

+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | published_time      | topped_time         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  4 | 2016-07-05 22:01:27 | 2016-07-06 00:00:00 |
|  6 | 2016-07-05 22:01:28 | 2016-05-06 00:00:00 |
|  5 | 2016-07-05 22:01:29 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 2016-07-05 22:01:25 | 2016-07-17 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2016-07-05 22:01:23 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 2016-07-05 22:01:14 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**UPDATE**

As you may notice I added additional row to prove that your solution is wrong

```
SELECT * FROM article 
ORDER BY topped_time < CURRENT_TIME() AND 
         topped_time DESC, published_time DESC;

+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | published_time      | topped_time         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  6 | 2016-07-05 22:01:28 | 2016-05-06 00:00:00 |
|  4 | 2016-07-05 22:01:27 | 2016-07-06 00:00:00 |
|  5 | 2016-07-05 22:01:29 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  3 | 2016-07-05 22:01:25 | 2016-07-17 00:00:00 |
|  2 | 2016-07-05 22:01:23 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 2016-07-05 22:01:14 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by custom column which should determine the order priority:

```
SELECT *, 
    IF(`topped_time` < CURRENT_TIME(), 1, 0) AS topOrder 
FROM `article` 
ORDER BY topOrder DESC, `published_time` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `article`
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `topped_time=` < CURRENT_TIME()
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END DESC,
         `published_time`  DESC
```

MySQL allows evaluates Boolean expressions as 1 and 0. So you can try :

```
SELECT * FROM `article`
ORDER BY `topped_time=` > CURRENT_TIME(),
         `published_time`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
 SELECT * FROM `article`
  ORDER BY case
   WHEN `topped_time` <= now() THEN 
    `topped_time` 
   ELSE 
    0
   END,`published_time`  
  DESC
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer, but i'm getting result of id 4,3,1,2,5, i'm expecting 4,5,3,2,1

Comment: Hi, actually I misread your question.and took published_time for condition.I have changed it now .It now gives 4,3,5,2,1. I am working on it ... will revert.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a working solution, however it leaves much to be desired.

```sql
SELECT 1 AS sort, a.* FROM (SELECT * FROM article
WHERE (topped_time < current_time()) AND (topped_time != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
ORDER BY published_time DESC, topped_time DESC) AS a
UNION
SELECT 2 AS sort, b.* FROM (SELECT * FROM article
WHERE (topped_time > current_time()) OR (topped_time = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
ORDER BY published_time DESC) as b
ORDER BY sort ASC, published_time DESC
```

[image]